# can't change the height of status bar control in a property page in win32

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have a windows application in which I am trying to create a status bar at the bottom of a PropertyPage. I have added a member variable of type `CStatusBarCtrl` named `m_StatBar` in the derived propertypage class.

Here is the code in the `OnInitDialog` of the PropertyPage

```
int nTotWide;       // total width of status bar
CRect rect3;
this->GetWindowRect(&rect3);
rect3.top = rect3.bottom - 70;

int m_bRvStatOk = m_StatBar.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE, rect3, this,IDC_STATUSBAR);
if (m_bRvStatOk == NULL)

{
    AfxMessageBox("Status Bar not created!", NULL, MB_OK);
}
//  get size of window, use to configure the status
//  bar with four separate parts

nTotWide = rect3.right - rect3.left;
//
// Make each part 1/4 of the total width of the window.
//
m_Widths[0] = nTotWide / 4;

m_Widths[1] = nTotWide / 2;

m_Widths[2] = nTotWide - m_Widths[0];

m_Widths[3] = -1;

m_StatBar.SetMinHeight(70);
m_StatBar.SetParts(4, m_Widths);
m_StatBar.SetText("TEXT WITH BORDER.", 0, 0);
m_StatBar.SetText("TEXT WITHOUT BORDER.", 1, SBT_NOBORDERS);
m_StatBar.SetText("TEXT POPUP.", 2, SBT_POPOUT);
```

I am not able to change the height of the status bar.
appreciate any help on the same.

Comment: I don't see where you're even trying to set the height (other than setting the minimum height, which only stops it from being **resized** below that minimum, which you don't attempt to do). All you set is the width of the 4 panels in the status bar.

Comment: As usual, the MFC [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatusbarctrl-class#setminheight) doesn't tell you the whole story. The implementation just sends an [SB_SETMINHEIGHT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/sb-setminheight) message. Now *that* documentation also tells you: *"An application must send the `WM_SIZE` message to the status window to redraw the window. The `wParam` and `lParam` parameters of the `WM_SIZE` message should be set to zero."*

Comment: thanks @iinspectable it works when the WM_SIZE message is sent with wParam=0 and lParama=0.

Comment: I'll post an answer then, just need to confirm that you are using MFC (as opposed to some other library, like WTL).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the height of a [status bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/status-bar-reference). However, you can request a minimum size by sending an [`SB_SETMINHEIGHT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/sb-setminheight) message to the control (which is what the [`CStatusBarCtrl::SetMinHeight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatusbarctrl-class#setminheight) implementation does).

This is not enough for the system to pick up the requested minimum height, though. While the MFC documentation doesn't provide any help or hint, the [`SB_SETMINHEIGHT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/sb-setminheight) documentation has the following remark:

> An application must send the [`WM_SIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size) message to the status window to redraw the window. The *`wParam`* and *`lParam`* parameters of the `WM_SIZE` message should be set to zero.

This translates to the following MFC implementation:

```cpp
m_StatBar.SetMinHeight(70);
m_StatBar.SendMessage(WM_SIZE);  // wParam and lParam have default arguments set to 0
```